# How to pass route parameters as numbers?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In the section [Passing Props to Route Components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components) of Vue documentation, they explain how to pass a parameter from the location path into the component, and they declare the props as an array. But in the [Style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-definitions-essential), they mention it is preferable to have props define (at least) their data type.

If i were to listen to the style guide, and if i wanted my URL to define id's of the entities they want to refer to (for example `/user/99`), then how would i pass that parameter as a number, and avoid the console error telling me it expected a number, but got a string? There are no examples of this.

In the line `{ path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: true }`, i would need some extra parameters specifying that `id` is of type `Numeric`. But how exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You can create a function that returns props. This allows you to cast
> parameters into other types, combine static values with route-based
> values, etc.

[Reference](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode).

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/user/:id',
      component: User,
      props: route => ({ id: Number(route.params.id) }),
    },
  ],
})
```

Comment: I try to get it in my component with `this.route.params.id` but i get a string, did I miss something?